# How to insert a horizontal line in a README.md file

Tags: readme, horizontal-line

I am trying to insert a horizontal line in a README.md file and I don't know how to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Insert a couple of dashes like this:

```
-----
```

And the result will be:

---

If the text on top of the dashes enlarges instead, then move the dashes down 1 line.

Comment: Or write <hr> in README.md